# Подскажите пакет для работы с Facebook на С#

Tags: c#, facebook

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь пакет для c#, для работы с Facebook.

Нужно собрать информацию о пользователях (ФИО, пол, дата, страна...) по имеющимся на них ссылкам.

Comment: Здесь не смотрели? https://hackerapp.com/

Comment: Да, уже столкнулся,думаю их и попробую использовать, спасибо.